# Images don't load in Firefox on my NextJS application

Tags: firefox, next.js, browser

I serve my site over this url.

Here is the code that I have in my `next.config.js` file for the cache policy:

```js
module.exports = {
  ...
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/:all*(svg|jpg|png|gif)',
        locale: false,
        headers: [
          {
            key: 'Cache-Control',
            value: 'public, max-age=5184000, must-revalidate',
          },
        ],
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

If you access the website with Chrome, there is no issue. But with Firefox, here is what you get:

[image]

[image]

Basically, the images are not being loaded correctly, and I don't understand the error... The other elements are being loaded correctly.

Another weird thing is that:

- If I do "Ctrl+Shift+R", none of the images will load.
- If I do "Ctrl+R", some will succeed to load.

It's as if the server needed some time before being able to load the images. I don't know NextJS enough to debug that, though...

Comment: Have you tried clearing/disabling cache? Also, you could try replacing `max-age=...` with `s-maxage=...`

Comment: Yes. Actually, the cleaner the cache, the more likely I am to meet the issue. This is the weird part. I'll try the thing about maxage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally nailed it!

Basically, custom protocol handlers like: `window.open(`myprotocol://open${params}`, '_self')` are immediately stopping the page from loading on Firefox. I'm not sure if this is expected, though.

I just had to wait for the page to load:

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  const onLoad = () => window.open(`myprotocol://open${params}`, '_self')
  window.addEventListener('load', onLoad)
  return () => window.removeEventListener('load', onLoad)
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same issue and setting a static value for `height` and `weight` did the job.

Update: the issue has more to do with CSS. here's an alternative fix that worked:

JSX:

```js
<span onClick={clickEvent} className='_image-wrapper'>
  <Image
    className='card-img-top'
    style={{
      width: '100%',
      objectFit: 'cover',
    }}
    fill
    placeholder='blur'
    blurDataURL={thumbnailObj.blurData}
    src={thumbnailObj.url}
    alt='Thumbnail avatar'
  ></Image>
</span>
```

CSS:

```css
._image-wrapper {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 45/28;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```